# GnuTLS error -110 in gnutls_record_recv: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I am trying to download some files from a server using FileZilla 3.9.0.5, using regular FTP over explicit TLS. Many files download just fine. It refuses to download certain files, however, giving me messages like the following:

```
Status: Starting download of /public_html/foo/bar/baz.php
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (***my server IP***)
Command:    RETR baz.php
Response:   150-Accepted data connection
Response:   150 13.0 kbytes to download
Error:  GnuTLS error -110 in gnutls_record_recv: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Status: Server did not properly shut down TLS connection
Error:  Could not read from transfer socket: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Response:   226-File successfully transferred
Response:   226 0.000 seconds (measured here), 26.04 Mbytes per second
Error:  File transfer failed after transferring 13,653 bytes in 1 second
```

The server in question is a CentOS/cPanel box.

Can someone tell me how to resolve this?

**EDIT:** Some additional insight: the files on which FileZilla melted down had some hard tabs (character 9). I replaced all hard tabs with 4 spaces in the copies of these files on the server, then was able to download them just fine. Maybe something about the tab characters caused the problem?

**EDIT 2:** The server logs just have lots of entries like this:

```
Sat Sep 13 18:24:26 2014 0 ****** 13682 /home/******/public_html/foo/bar/baz.php a _ o r ****** ftp 1 * c
```

The `******`s above represent the IP, username, and username again for the account in question. Except for the time stamp and number of bytes transferred, the entries for failed transfers are identical to the successful ones.

Answer (score 2):

This is Filezilla issue & i am not sure how to fix it but a quick solution is to use a different FTP client.

I used [Core FTP](http://www.coreftp.com/) & it works fine.

Comment: Can you provide any more information, such as documentation that this is actually a FileZilla issue or an explanation of why it is happening?

Comment: Sorry i lost the link but it was some where in filezilla forums, althought the filezilla guys kept saying it's server issue but it's not & core ftp being able to do what filezilla cant is the proof.

Comment: I manage to log in with some another client also after receiving this error in filezilla

Comment: I got this problem with FileZilla client trying to list a directory from hMailServer (latest version 5.6.7 - Build 2425 which is 3 years old).  It only happened on one directory and that directory had 500+ files in it.  I was able to RDP into the server and split the folder into two and the listing (and subsequent downloads) worked.  Looks like a problem with large directory listings and hMailServer in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> Status: Server did not properly shut down TLS connection

This is a problem caused by the server so you need to have to look at the server logs.
Essentially it says, that the server just closed the TCP connection without properly shutting down the TLS layer on top of the TCP connection first. If this is some well-known server software this should hopefully not happen and you might find some relevant log entries on the server side. But, if this is just some self-made or rarely used server software it might be a problem of the server software itself, because failing to properly shutdown an TLS connection is an error often made.

Comment: I understand what the messages mean; I just don't know what to do about them. Like I said in my question, this is a cPanel box; it is running Pure-FTPD, which is the default FTP server for cPanel.

Comment: How about looking at the server logs like suggested?

Comment: BTW, if you search for the error message in connection with pure-ftpd it looks like a problem not only you have.

Comment: Please see my edit above. I have looked at the server logs, and they contain nothing interesting. Also, yes, I know lots of people have this problem. I have not found any solutions or even explanations, however, which is why I'm asking here.

Comment: I would say it's a server side thing. Since there are no information which version of pure-ftpd you are using I would suggest to try the latest, but TLS support is still marked experimental even in the latest version.